# Let X equal the number of flips of a fair coin that are required to observe heads–tails on consecutive flips.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

[image]
[image: L]

For (b). When calculating Moment generating function, I don't get how the solution manual jumps from the $\sum_{x=1}^\infty x*(\frac{e^t}{2})^x- \sum_{x=1}^\infty (\frac{e^t}{2})^x$ to $(\frac{1}{(1-\frac{e^t}{2})^2}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}})$-$\frac{\frac{e^t}{2}}{1-\frac{e^t}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses two identities:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k &= \frac{z}{1-z}\\
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k z^k &= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} - \frac{1}{1-z}
\end{align}